# Count distinct values based on criteria in multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

I have a table like this from which I want to count of recurrences per Username. I would like to count how many distinct `Type` are there with `Amount <> 0` per user:

```
+----------+-------------+--------+
| Username |    Type     | Amount |
+----------+-------------+--------+
| abc      | New         |      1 |
| abc      | New         |      1 |
| abc      | Old         |      1 |
| def      | New         |      1 |
| def      | Old         |      0 |
| def      | Refurbished |      1 |
| ijk      | New         |      1 |
| ijk      | Old         |      2 |
| ijk      | Refurbished |      3 |
+----------+-------------+--------+
```

My result should look something like this:

```
+----------+---------------+
| Username | DistinctCount |
+----------+---------------+
| abc      |             2 |
| def      |             2 |
| ijk      |             3 |
+----------+---------------+
```

..where `[Username] abc` has `2 distinct [Type]` with `[Amount] not equal to 0`.

I have tried `SELECT DISTINCT Type, Username, SUM(CASE WHEN Amount <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM tblBase GROUP BY Type, Username` but it's not yielding the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `COUNT DISTINCT` with `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    Username,
    DistinctCount = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Amount <> 0 THEN Type END)
FROM #tbl
GROUP BY Username;
```

The difference with using `WHERE` clause is that, this will return rows with 0 `DistinctCount`, while the `WHERE` clause will not.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/448045)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect!

Comment: It's also the worst solution, isn't it?  It's inefficient because you're considering all rows, even when zero.  I bet this would run worse in the majority of use cases...

Comment: @MattG, maybe. But this is completely different from yours and Backtrack's solution using the `WHERE` condition. If he intend to exclude 0 rows, then the `WHERE` clause would be correct and this one's wrong. Otherwise, it's the only correct solution here.

Answer (score 3):

According to your output, you want one row per username.  That means you want to group by username.  You want to count the number of distinct types by username, and there's an aggregate function for that.  Try this:

```
SELECT    username, 
          COUNT(DISTINCT Type) as counted 
FROM      tblBase 
WHERE     Amount <> 0 
GROUP BY  username
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT Username, COUNT(DISTINCT Type) AS DistinctCount
    FROM tblBase  WHERE Amount <> 0 
    GROUP BY Username
```

I would say, use Amount <> 0  in `Where` and `group by` using username. And use `distinct` to get the count